# Simple icon to represent vibration?

Tags: icon

I'm looking for a simple icon to represent vibration. It can't be too similar to the sound icon because I'm going to put it right below a sound icon (the speaker shape). I was thinking something with waves but I'm not too sure. Maybe you guys would have some ideas?

Comment: What don't you like about regular vibration icons that you can find with a Google search.

Comment: What context? architecture, machinery, geology, music...?

Comment: I hope its for a sex toy. Would make this way more interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Try representing vibration with three jagged horizontal lines parallel to one another. Think of the lines on a seismograph that monitors earthquakes.

Answer (score 1):

If I need inspiration I go to [shutterstock](http://www.shutterstock.com) and see what the keyword gives me

for example -

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Something to notice here is how they often use **straight lines instead of curves** which are associated with sound. [Another example here uses **jagged lines**](http://thenounproject.com/term/earthquake/21862/) to show vibration. Feels more physical.

Comment: I like the freebody diagram of lumped system drawing. But im sure no normal person will get it. But a jackhammer is not a bad idea loose the person tough.